# Videos will be played to fast (e.g.: youtube, or via VLC), Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, video

Problem  :
If I set the refresh rate (Gnome settings) from 30 frames per second to 50 frames per second, the videos will be played to fast(approximately twice of original speed), the sound is also to fast, but it seems synchronized to video.

PC connected via HDMI to TV

Kernel :  5.15.0-30-generic

Output of : sudo lshw -c video

*-display
Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller

```
   Produkt: Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X]

   Hersteller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]

   Physische ID: 0

   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0

   Logischer Name: /dev/fb0

   Version: e5

   Breite: 64 bits

   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   Konfiguration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
   Ressourcen: irq:36 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(Größe=256) memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

output of :  lsmod | grep amd

amdgpu               9723904  20

iommu_v2               24576  1 amdgpu

gpu_sched              45056  1 amdgpu

drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 amdgpu

ttm                    86016  2 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper

drm_kms_helper        307200  1 amdgpu

i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu

drm                   606208  14 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm

I hope someone can help.
If further information will be needed, I will add it.

Comment: The refresh rate should be set to your displays native refresh rate. This is typically 60Hz

Comment: I did check it also with 60Hz, same behavior. From my side of experience all fresh rates are allowed until the max. value will be reached, given by the monitor restrictions. An additional hint : The max. refresh value given by Ubuntu 20.04 + Gnome + same HW : 30 frames/s, and this value also works on Ubuntu 22.04. .

Comment: Back to Ubuntu 20.04, and currently there also 60Hz does work. Try again 22.04, default settings 60Hz used, and now it works. Had problems with missing Grub windows entry but with the help of : https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/12/grub-doesnt-detect-windows-linux-distros-fix, it could be fixed.